# "Inadequate resource type access" when creating Azure Blob SAS key in C#

Tags: c#, azure

I am creating a SAS key in my C# code, like below.

```
        string returnValue = String.Empty;
        // Create a new access policy for the account with the following properties:
        SharedAccessAccountPolicy policy = new SharedAccessAccountPolicy()
        {
            Permissions = SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Read | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Write | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Create,
            Services = SharedAccessAccountServices.Blob,
            ResourceTypes = SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Container | SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Object,
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(10),
            Protocols = SharedAccessProtocol.HttpsOrHttp
        };

        // Create new storage credentials using the SAS token.
        ExecuteWithExceptionHandling(
                () =>
                {
                    returnValue = storageAccount.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);                        
                });
        return returnValue;
```

This code generates a key properly. But when I try to use this key in Azure Storage Explorer, I get an error saying `Inadequate resource type access. At least service-level ('s') access is required.`

When I try to use this key from javascript to create a container, I get an error saying `Refused to set unsafe header "user-agent"` in `azure-storage-blob.min.js` file (came from azure storage api by microsoft).

I have added the create permission in `SharedAccessAccountPolicy`, but the key generated is not working for some reason.

Edit:
Javascript code to create blobservice.

```
    var blobService = AzureStorage.Blob.createBlobServiceWithSas(blobUri, $("#SASToken").val());
blobService.createContainerIfNotExists(folderID, function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Edit:
Below is a screenshot of the azure portal, where I tried to generate manual token. Even that token has `ss=b` in it instead of `sr=b` as per the document.

I tried the token I generated manually. And the JS code still says `Refused to set unsafe header "user-agent"`.

[image: Azure Portal]

Comment: Can you share your SAS token? You can obfuscate the `signature` portion of it.

Comment: ?sv=2015-07-08&sig=xi2R7H%2B0iJc%3D&spr=https%2Chttp&se=2018-08-14T22%3A49%3A39Z&srt=co&ss=b&sp=rcw

Here. Deleted part of the signature.

Comment: Your sig says ss=b, I think that should read sr=b according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1

Comment: That's weird. I am not sure, why that is coming wrong. Am I probably missing some settings in blob? When I generate token from azure portal, that one also comes with ss=b. Clearly something is missing from my settings.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is an issue with the damn js file provided by Azure. 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/issues/463
Here is an open ticket about it.

Anyway, for now, I have added a condition to ensure header is not added. If the code still fails, I will create a different question.

I think, within 2 days, I can just take the latest update of the Azure's js and this should fix itself. Still in case, anyone needs a quick fix, here is the code change done by me.

`if (e[0] != 'user-agent'){ s.setRequestHeader(e[0],e[1])}}`

instead of `s.setRequestHeader(e[0],e[1])}`

It is only a temporary fix. Best option is still to update to version 2.10.101 or higher for azure storage js file.